# Multiple Author with link and image

Tags: multi-author

I have a blog with multiple authors. 
Each author has an image inside the "/ wp-content/themes/mytheme/img/authornamecomeshere.png" directory, and each image has the author's name. 
I would like to put a link from these sites reviewers along with the image, and each image automatically appear under the name.

The code I'm using is this:

```
<?php _e('Posted by'); ?> 

<a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>" rel="author">

<img src="/wp-content/themes/mytheme/img/authornamecomeshere.png" alt="author" />

<?php the_author_meta('display_name'); ?>

</a>
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
Posted by: 
if author1: <a href="author1site.com"><img src="/wp-content/themes/mytheme/img/author1.png" /></a>

Posted by: 
if author2: <a href="author2sitesite.com"><img src="/wp-content/themes/mytheme/img/author2.png" /></a>
```

I'd like do this without plugin.
Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get_the_author_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta) to retrieve the username for the author of the current post in the loop. You could then use that in the image URL.

```
<?php _e('Posted by'); ?> 

<a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>" rel="author">

<img src="/wp-content/themes/mytheme/img/<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'user_login' ) ); ?>.png" alt="author" />

<?php the_author_meta('display_name'); ?>

</a>
```

You can also use `get_the_author_meta` if the image file name is a combination of the author's first and last name, by passing 'first_name' or 'last_name' to the function to retrieve these values.

Comment: Hi! Just a doubt rs The image is a combination of the author's name, the image and name of the author of the post is the same, but the image that is showing is as if there was not a directory. I used the 'first_name'.  THX!